# Google Maps V3 not loading (Asked & Answered) 

Tags: javascript, maps

This question is already answered. I discovered what the problem is. 
But, I'm posting the Q&A here because others may be in the same predicament.

My google map code came from samples I found on the web.

In the "bad" code there was a line that looked like this:

```
var latlng= new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.Ua, results[0].geometry.location.Va);
```

This code worked until last night. 
Using firebug to inspect the objects, it turns out that location is now of the form: {Ta: number, Ua: number}

My immediate fix was to use the lat() and lng() methods whenever I required the lat and/or lng.

The other fix was to instantiate my map in a more intelligent fashion.

Yes, it was silly rely upon properties uncovered deep in an object using the firebug inspector. Yes, being a google maps noob and relying on copy paste with little or no knowledge reaped its just rewards.

But, doing a quick google seach found many folks (other than the "sample" I borrowed from) also using the .Va property directly.

Hence the post here in case this is their problem too.

Comment: if it was answered then people would find it through that, no need to do this. You may request a deletion which will not affect your reputation in my opinion, or others gonna delete it anyways. :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Feel free to edit your question into a real question and provide an answer yourself. But as it stands it's not a real question and will probably be closed as such.

Comment: I was attempting to follow the advice on http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ in asking and ansering this question. Perhaps that approach is out of fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you're interested in *why* this happened, it's simple: the sample was using undocumented internals of the API, so when Google updated the Maps JS file, it broke.

More specifically, `Ua` and `Va` were auto-generated variable names resulting from [minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29).  It looks like Google removed a variable in the original source and the labels shifted up (`Ua`,`Va` → `Ta`,`Ua`).

I'll bet I know exactly how the author of the bad sample came up with his code.  He inspected a [`LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) (the type of object in `location` in your example) in his browser's dev tools, saw that those two oddly-named variables contained the data he wanted, and just went with it.  Since the `lat` and `lng` methods are "hidden" in `LatLng`'s `prototype`, he didn't notice them.

There are two lessons to be learned here:

1. **Always use [documented API methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)**; anything else is an implementation detail that is subject to change.
2. Don't trust the code on some dude's website is a *good* or even competent example of how to do things.  This is especially true in the case of Google Maps, where there's extensive documentation and official examples.

Comment: Duh..... Shows how new I am. Never even thought about minification. Thanks for taking the time to give the explanation.